# HttpWebRequest reinterpretting response

Tags: c#, rest, httpwebrequest, salesforce

I am using the following code to post (create) an object in a RESTful web service.

```
            JObject lead = new JObject();
        lead.Add(new JProperty("FirstName", "John"));
        lead.Add(new JProperty("LastName", "Doe"));
        lead.Add(new JProperty("Company", "Acme"));

        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://na15.salesforce.com/services/data/v25.0/sobjects/Lead") as HttpWebRequest;
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.Accept = "application/json";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Headers["Authorization"] = string.Format("Bearer {0}", "xxxxxx");

        using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(requestStream))
            {
                writer.Write(lead.ToString());
            }
        }

        using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            if (response.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    // do something with response stream
                }                
            }
        }
```

The following is what I capture in Fiddler for the request and response.

```
REQUEST:

POST https://na15.salesforce.com/services/data/v25.0/sobjects/Lead HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer <<TOKEN>>
Host: na15.salesforce.com
Content-Length: 71
Expect: 100-continue

{
  "FirstName": "John",
  "LastName": "Doe",
  "Company": "Acme"
}


RESPONSE:

HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Date: Mon, 21 Oct 2013 21:42:10 GMT
Sforce-Limit-Info: api-usage=19/5000
Location: /services/data/v25.0/sobjects/Lead/00Qi0000009RIFCEA4
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 54

{"id":"00Qi0000009RIFCEA4","success":true,"errors":[]}
```

However it seems that .NET is intepretting the response headers as the following ignoring the Content-Length header and adding a Transfer-Encoding header set to chunked.

```
Sforce-Limit-Info: api-usage=21/5000
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date: Mon, 21 Oct 2013 21:42:10 GMT
Location: /services/data/v25.0/sobjects/Lead/00Qi0000009RIFCEA4
```

Why does it do this and is there anyway to override this behavior?

Comment: support for chunked transfer encoding is a requirement of http 1.1. Why do you care if the response is chunked or not, either way .NET is going to give you a stream to read over.

Comment: The transfer encoding header is not a requirement for 1.1, it's optional.  The reason I want to know is so that I can check if a response has a response body.  But I can't because .NET always replaces the Content-Length with a Transfer-Encoding header even when a content length has been specified which makes no sense.  You would think that .NET would list the response headers exactly the same as the actual response.

Comment: However since Salesforce returns a 204 (no content) status code for responses with no body I will use that as an indicator.  Just seems ridiculous that .NET does not list out the headers exactly as they are in the actual response.